# Android, How can I load long text into an activity?

Tags: android, text, android-intent, scroll

I have a long text that I want to show it page by page. For my first try, I created 10 activity and put some button that when user clicks On it, next activity shows.

I read somewhere that I can load all my text in one activity with using Intent. is it possible? How it is possible?
I don't want user scroll the page.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give some more detail? Is this original text (something that may be worthwhile putting in strings.xml), or something you want to read from a file?

Comment: how you know if text fits specific devices (different dpi)?

Comment: Thanks Lawngnomehitman, and sorry for my incomplete information. yes, In XML I have a very long text, such as each chapters of a book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have your activity called `MyTextActivity`, then in your button click listener, you pass on the text you want into an intent to your activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyTextActivity.class);
i.putExtra("myText", "this is the text you want to display in the next page");
startActivity(i);
```

Then in your `MyTextActivity`, you put the following in `onCreate()`:

```
String textToDisplay = "";
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null){
   textToDisplay = extras.getString("myText");
}
```

then you set your TextView text to this text.

Comment: another improvement is to have your strings in some sort of array or list, then in your `putExtra()` function you just pass the index of the item you want to display. So when you click next you just increment your index (assuming you do proper index checking). So your change would be `i.putExtra("myTextIndex", index)` where index is an integer. Then when you retrieve it you would do `extra.getInt("myTextIndex")`

Comment: he said that he want to load a looooooooooong text , so he must change the title , it's a small text lool :) ,

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have a TextView and a Button in your activity, when the Button is pressed you do not need to go to a new activity. Instead, you can change the content of your existing text view. Just use TextView.setText() to change it.

Comment: Thanks it is good suggestion but it has a problem. How can I handle different size of screen sizes?

Answer (score 0):

If the text is static,you can put it in a string resource and access it in all your activities. Otherwise, you can attach the string to the intent, using `putExtra`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is "don't do this". Android runs on a variety of devices, and you should handle the cases where it won't fit on the screen that matches the device you're using for testing. Consider tablets, for example.